# Odds for drawing from a full deck of cards or a split deck of cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I’m playing a card game with my family. (Sequence if you’re curious).

Now there are 2 decks of 52 cards in the pile. And each turn a player draws a card.

I suggested that we split the deck in to 2 piles. So that it would be easier for players on the other side of the table to reach. So 3 players would pick from one pile and 3 would pick from the other. Rather than have all 6 reach to draw from the one pile.

However everyone in my family objected saying this would alter the chances of drawing a card. As some of the cards would be in the other half and they would have no chance of drawing them. I tried to explain that splitting the deck does not alter their chances. They disagreed.

Am I missing something or am I correct? Can you explain it in a way that would be simple for everyone to understand.

TLDR: in a game where each player takes turns drawing from the deck. Are the odds the same drawing from one deck? Or splitting the deck in two and having some players draw from one half and some from the other half.

Comment: Assuming the cards are well shuffled, it does not matter. This is similat to a lottery , $100$ tickets one winning the main prize. If noone knows where the ticket with the main price is , you have no disadvantage if you are the last to draw.

Comment: The fallacy with the argument with the wrong half is that chances are also increased if the cards are in the right half , apparently this has not been considered.

Comment: I think the good way to resolve this is: people who agree the odds are the same just draw from the closer pile; people who disagree can draw from whatever pile they want. The odds still don't change and everyone is happy.

Comment: Use a smaller table, so all can select at will, then there will be peace while playing. Otherwise, the "discontented" players you wish to play with will scatter.

Comment: Put a "lazy susan" (rotatable surface on bearings) in the middle of the table, so the players can obtain the card they choose.

Comment: Is Charlie more or less likely to win a golden ticket to the chocolate factory if the tickets are spread randomly across many small shops, or if you could only obtain tickets by queuing outside Willy Wonka's factory?